# Do not print Maven Goals and options command to Console Output in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, console

I am passing a secret value using -D in maven Goals and options on jenkins. I don't want to output this secret value to console for security reasons. e.g. maven command in Goals and option on Jenkins look like this:

```
clean install -DnewSecret=newGeneratedSecret
```

When the job is run this is printed in console output:

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f /workspace/pom.xml clean install -DnewSecret=newGeneratedSecret
```

Any idea how to stop printing this? I tried these but didn't work:

```
clean install -q -DnewSecret=newGeneratedSecret
clean install -DnewSecret=newGeneratedSecret > null
```

**Update:** please note the secret value is a generated value which is then set as env variable using EnvInject jenkins plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Mask Passwords Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin) to define a masked variable for `newSecret` (e.g., named "SECRET") under **Build Environment > Mask Passwords** and then use it in your Maven options as an environment variable:

```
clean install -DnewSecret=${SECRET}
```

The console would show this:

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f /workspace/pom.xml clean install -DnewSecret=**********
```

Comment: thanks but my secrets are generated within code (groovy) I can't set them manually.

Comment: Ok, that's worth clarifying. How are you configuring your Maven options?

Comment: I write the generated secret to a prop file and then I am using EnvInject plugin to create environment variables. In build step there is an input box "Goals and option" where I am passing the env to maven